# Creating/disposing database context in a long running program that writes several thousand records

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a long running program that writes several thousand records to a PostgreSQL database each day using a repository pattern

That looks something like this:

```
public class Demo {

    public IProductRepository productRepository { get; }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        productRepository = new DependencyResolver(ConfigureServices).ServiceProvider.GetService<IProductRepository>();

        //list of products just for demo purposes
        List<Product> productList = getMagicalProductList();

        //do the work here
        foreach (Product p in productList) {
            productRepository.AddProduct(p);
        }
    }

    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
    }

}
```

And `ProductRepository` looks like this:

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository {

    public MyDbContext Context { get; }

    public ProductRepository(MyDbContext context) {
        Context = context;
    }

    public void AddProduct(Product product) {
        Context.products.Add(product);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

Now if you look at the `//do the work here` section in my `Demo.Main()` method, you'll see that it's using the same context to insert all Product objects in the list. Is that a bad thing? If I create a new context for each iteration of the loop, isn't that going to be a waste of resources?

Also, let's say I wanted to create a new context each time, what would that look like in the code? The repository pattern is responsible for handling the context, so it looks like I would have to change something in there that would allow it to automatically create and dispose contexts with each call.

***Update:*** I ended up changing my code to process the data in batches, so it now creates a new context for each batch and calls `SaveChanges()` only once at the end of each batch.

Comment: Well, creating a new context each time would mean generating thousands of contexts - a complete waste of resources. More importantly, I'd batch the `SaveChanges` call (i.e. call it once every 100-1000 records). Generally though, repository pattern with EF means duplicating effort for no good reason (EF already implements Repository and UoW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call SaveChanges after each product addition. It is not effective. Call `SaveChanges` once.

Also, if you care about performance, I would suggest to do not use EF Core's Change Tracker to seed database with such amount of data. There are extensions which may insert that data in several seconds, for example [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

```cs
context.BulkCopy(new BulkCopyOptions(), productList);
```

Comment: If I call SaveChanges() after inserting let's say 100,000 items, wouldn't that use up a lot of memory? Also, what if I wanted to be sure that the change was committed to the database because that's going to kick off a separate process to do some more work on that newly inserted piece of data?

Comment: Sure, after each SaveChanges call. EF generates new SQL makes roundtrip to database, registers entity in change tracker. Stores copy of old values. Maybe something else.

Comment: The more items you insert, the more time ChangeTracker uses to detect changes.

Comment: What do I do if I want EF to forget about the newly added items? Those objects are not referenced anywhere after they are added to the database, so I thought the garbage collector would pick them up anyway.

Comment: If you insert several items, call SaveChanges once. After that you have to dispose DataContext, usually it is done by scoped IoC container. Then memory should be collected.

Comment: Yes, but in this case I am inserting several thousand items, and each item needs to be committed to the database because it kicks off a separate task that does some further concurrent processing on the newly inserted data.

Comment: What is the problem? You have overridden SaveChanges and starts some complex processing?

Comment: There was no problem. I changed my code to only call SaveChanges() once every 100 records. In my code, I omitted a part where it sends a message to a queue telling a separate task to begin further processing the data which it picks up from the database, but it should be okay even if that happens every 100 records.

Comment: Nice, it is better. Even better, you can recreate context for every 100-1000  records, it will simplify changes detection. Because EF remembers your previously inserted data and trying to detect changes in already saved data.